# Split the filename based upon delimiter is giving syntax error: unexpected "(" (expecting "done") in bash/sh

Tags: string, bash, shell, for-loop

Looping in the current directory and checking if the file extension ends with yaml, then split the filename on dot and perform other operations.
Below is my code.

What's wrong here? I'm getting error like: `syntax error: unexpected "(" (expecting "done")`

```
for fname in $(find . -name '*.yaml' -exec basename {} \;); do
  echo "Printing filename $fname"
  ARR=(${fname//./ })
  echo "${ARR[0]}"
done
```

Comment: You are using a shell that cannot handle arrays.

Comment: what can I do to achieve the result as above?

Comment: Show how to start the script.

Comment: this script is getting executed in a Tekton pipeline. 

under`script: |-`

Comment: I assume that the script is started with `sh` instead of `bash`. This might help: `bash script.sh`

Comment: No, I have directly return the code above under `script: |-` without any header as sh or bash.

Comment: @Cyrus by default it is getting started with `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: So, any recommendation on how do I get its work now?

Comment: Use `basename "$fname" .yaml` to print the base name of the file without the file extension.  No need for the array at all, nor is there a need to echo the result because `basename` writes to standard output anyway.  Unless, perhaps, you might have a name like `part1.part2.yaml`, in which case your script would echo `part1` and `basename "$fname" .yaml` would echo `part1.part2`.

Comment: I have a name like part1.part2.part3.yaml and that's why I have to break this name on dot and then use part1, part2, part3 to execute different parts of the script.

Comment: Can you post and answer with description. That will be fantastic.

Comment: The array manipulation here is just crazy. Assuming you don't have file names with newlines in them, `find . -name '*.yaml' | sed 's%.*/\([^/.]*\)\.[^/]*$%\1%'`

Answer (score -1):

This script may be able to meet your needs:

```
for fname in *.yaml; do
  echo "Printing filename $fname"
  ARR[i]=`echo $fname | sed 's/\..*//'`
  echo "${ARR[i]}"
  i=$i+1;
done
```